# Частично не переведена страница с выходом из сети StackExchange

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

При попытке выхода из сети *StackExchange* отсутствует перевод текста у чекбокса:

[image: log out on all devices]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаемый перевод:

> Выйти на всех устройствах